# Get a range based on conditions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Say that I have this SQL table:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| TxnDate                   |  TxnType           |  ComputerName      |  User       |
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+

| 2022-08-01T00:00:53.000Z  |  PowerOn           |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:01:41.000Z  |  PowerOn           |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:01:57.000Z  |  UserSignIn        |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:02:39.000Z  |  CheckEmail        |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:04:48.000Z  |  UserSignIn        |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:22.000Z  |  DownloadMovie     |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:42.000Z  |  PowerOn           |  PC_BWZONE_0003    | system      |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:48.000Z  |  PrintRecipe       |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:53.000Z  |  UserSignOut       |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:02.000Z  |  DownloadUpdate    |  PC_BWZONE_0003    | system      |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:03.000Z  |  UserSignOut       |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:04.000Z  |  QueryTimeServer   |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:04.000Z  |  DownloadUpdate    |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:41.000Z  |  PowerOff          |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | system         |
| 2022-08-01T00:08:27.000Z  |  DownloadUpdate    |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | system      |
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

As you can see this table has some sample data that shows an event log of sorts.

Say that I only care about what happens on these computers between `UserSignIn` and `UserSignOut` of each user who signs into a computer.  I am not concerned with any tasks happening before or after a user session (for example, the `system` user does not log in at all, so there are no user sessions for `system`).

How do I take this "raw" table data and filter it to show something more like this (doesn't have to be exact, but you'll get my meaning in a second:

```
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| TxnDate                   |  TxnType           |  ComputerName      |  User       |
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
| 2022-08-01T00:01:57.000Z  |  UserSignIn        |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:02:39.000Z  |  CheckEmail        |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:22.000Z  |  DownloadMovie     |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:53.000Z  |  UserSignOut       |  PC_BWZONE_0002    | dad         |
| 2022-08-01T00:04:48.000Z  |  UserSignIn        |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:06:48.000Z  |  PrintRecipe       |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
| 2022-08-01T00:07:03.000Z  |  UserSignOut       |  PC_BWZONE_0001    | mom         |
+---------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+
```

My real table has thousands of records so however I end up doing this it needs to be scalable.

Sql Version:  Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3513.0 (X64)

Answer (score 0):

Don't want system?  Just filter it out.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE [User] != 'system'
ORDER BY [User], TxnDate
```

Comment: `USER` is a reserved keyword, so needs delimit identifying.

Comment: I think sql server would be find without it but I added them just for you @larnu <3

Comment: No, it wouldn't be fine without it, @Hogan . Without it you would get an error "Incorrect syntax near keyword 'User'.".

Comment: Maybe I need to make my table have more complicated data.  This isn't that simple

Comment: I edited my question.  I need only the user sessions  (>= time of UserSignIn && <= time of UserSignOut)